# How can I fix my code so that the Discord command functions?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am building a bot for Discord, and wanted to make a command to simplify governing spam. I have put the bot's role above all other roles, however, the general bot role is near the bottom. I am looking to create a command that will perform this function by running /spamhammer @user. However, the command does nothing, and no errors are shown in the console.

My code:

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "/spamhammer ") {
    if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
    let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])); 
    if (!rMember) return message.reply("That user does not exist.");
    let gRole = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'SpamHammer'); 

    rMember.removeRoles(rMember.roles).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
    rMember.addRole(gRole.id);


    message.channel.send("User got the SpamHammer :spamhammer:."); 

    
  } else {
    message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use this command.");
  }
}});
```

The desired outcome is for all roles to be stripped from the user, and to automatically have the SpamHammer role applied. Thanks!

Comment: What version of discord.js are you on?

Comment: @MrMythical 12.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `msg` at the top, while using `message` in the rest of your code. Change all occurrences of `message` to `msg`, or vice versa.

---

### You may also have to do this:

---

You have to change

```js
msg.content === "/spamhammer"
```

to

```js
msg.content.startsWith("/spamhammer")
```

Right now you are checking if a user sends this exact message:

> /spamhammer

while you want the user to send

> /spamhammer @user

By changing the above, you check if the message **starts with** `"/spamhammer"` rather than checking if the message is exactly `/spamhammer`.

Then after changing it, you can check if the message has arguments etc. etc.

Comment: I have noticed that after testing the command, (this only started a few minutes after I posted this question) the console reads: `/home/runner/The-dragon-bot/index.js:18
    if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
    ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    ...
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1

Comment: Ah then I'm pretty certain that you are using `msg` and `message` in mixed places. e.g. `if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES'))` should be `if (msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES'))` (I actually think it should be `msg.author...` but that's off topic.